# Можно ли занести в базу дату и время вместе?

Tags: phpmyadmin, php

Здравствуйте! можно ли занести в одно поле дату и время? `date("Y-m-d, H:i:s")` Или все таки нужно использовать отдельные поля в phpMyAdmin: date и set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в MySQL есть тип `datetime`, полный шаблон данных для него `0000-00-00 00:00:00`, так что можно так и использовать (не переводя в юникстайм), только не забывать кавычки при использовании пробела, как и в других разделителесодерщих полях.

Answer (score 1):

Можно занести `unixTime` в поле. Там и дата и время.